# Data distribution in btrfs single profile array: using file instead of block level?

Tags: btrfs

I have an array of 3 different drives which I use in single profile (no raid). I don't use raid because the data isn't that important to spend some extra money for additioinal drives.

But what I could not figure out exactly is on what granularity the data is distributed on the 3 drives.

I could find this on the [wiki page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices):

> When you have drives with differing sizes and want to use the full
>   capacity of each drive, you have to use the single profile for the
>   **data blocks**, rather than raid0

As far as I understand this means that not the whole files are distributed/allocated on one of the 3 drives but each of the file's data blocks.

This is unfortunate because losing only 1 drive will destroy the whole array. Is there a possibility to balance a single profile array at a file level?
I would be fine with the risk of losing all files on 1 drive in the array but not losing the whole array if 1 drive fails.